# Compile C# program with Mono in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: ubuntu, mono

According to this https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin, I've installed mono-devel, then according to this https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/ I run csc, but it says csc is currently not installed and suggests me to install chicken-bin which I feel has nothing to do with Mono.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The answer is, it is mono-csc instead of csc. I found this by "which mono" then "ls /usr/bin/mono*"